# How to change from 30fps in the animation view (not render)?

Tags: animation

I'm trying to figure out how to change the fps for when I press the play button in the scene.

It automatically uses 30fps and moves down if the animation uses to much resource.

I want to force it to a specific fps (1fps or 2fps etc)

thanks

[image]

Comment: Also relevant: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14236/low-fps-on-animation-playback

Comment: thanks man, that worked, never thought the render would also affect the viewport

Answer (score 1):

In time remapping, put ***New*** to something like 1000.
This will slow down the playback to 3 fps.