# 2.9.1 Low FPS on Playback

Tags: animation

In Blender 2.79 I could hide everything except the head I wanted to do lipsync animations with, and I could get 22 - 24 FPS.  When I try it in 2.9.1 I'm getting 9 FPS.  Is there a setting that got unset that makes it choppier in 2.9.1?

I've tried all the ideas here :
[Low FPS on Animation Playback](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14236/low-fps-on-animation-playback)

I don't have any modifier on the head except hair, and I've turned that off and it hasn't made much of a difference.  I'm using shape keys to do the mouth movements.  Any ideas?